# How to set up a basic Go project with neural networks?

Tags: go

I am super new go `Go` and need some help setting things up. First, the `$GOPATH`. It seems that all of my `go` projects should be in the same place on my machine? So I have that set:

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/sites/gopath
```

Inside, I set up the folders recommended:

```
$ ls -a /sites/gopath
.   ..  bin pkg src
```

Inside `src`, I have a folder called `github.com`, which has a folder in it called `shamoons` which has a folder in it called `go-ann-test`.

Inside that, I have a folder called `autompg` and inside that, I have a file called `autompg.go`.

Phew! That's a lot of set up for a project! But I'm going assume that I'm either doing it wrong or that it's somehow worth it.

In my `autompg.go`, I have:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/fxsjy/gonn"
)

func main() {
  nn := gonn.DefaultNetwork(2,3,1,true)
  inputs := [][]float64{
    []float64{0,0},
    []float64{0,1},
    []float64{1,0},
    []float64{1,1},
  }

  targets := [][]float64{
    []float64{0},//0+0=0
    []float64{1},//0+1=1
    []float64{1},//1+0=1
    []float64{2},//1+1=2
  }

  nn.Train(inputs,targets,1000)

  for _,p := range inputs{
    fmt.Println(nn.Forward(p))
  }
}
```

And when I type `go install autompg` from my `go-ann-test` folder, I get:

```
$ go install autompg 
can't load package: package autompg: cannot find package "autompg" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.1/libexec/src/autompg (from $GOROOT)
    /sites/gopath/src/autompg (from $GOPATH)
```

So what am I doing wrong and how can I properly set up the project to accept the external package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `go install autompg` from my `go-ann-test` folder:

No, you need to go to the `go-ann-test/autompg` folder, and there type `go install`

That will compile `autompg.go` into an executable `autompg` and put in in your `$GOPATH/bin`.

Finally, you can add, commit and push to https://github.com/shamoons/go-ann-test.

The [OP Shamoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239879/shamoon) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374371/how-to-set-up-a-basic-go-project-with-neural-networks/28374461?noredirect=1#comment45090117_28374461):

> I get

```
 autompg.go:35:3: no buildable Go source files in /sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn
```

That means a `go get github.com/fxsjy/gonn` is needed to import and compile `github.com/fxsjy/gonn` first.

Considering that imported repo structure https://github.com/fxsjy/gonn, it actually needed:

```
cd /sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn/gonn
go install
```

That means the actual import was:

```
import github.com/fxsjy/gonn/gonn
```

Comment: I get `autompg.go:35:3: no buildable Go source files in /sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn`

Comment: you need to do first a `go get github.com/fxsjy/gonn`

Comment: @Shamoon then remove it from your import list: it doesn't seem that you are using that import in your example.

Comment: @Shamoon do you have git installed? What `git --version` return?

Comment: `git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)`

Comment: @Shamoon `go get github.com/fxsjy/gonn` should have cloned the repo https://github.com/fxsjy/gonn to your `$GOPATH/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn`.

Comment: Okay, started from scratch and now here's what happens when i `go get`, `package github.com/fxsjy/gonn
 imports github.com/fxsjy/gonn
 imports github.com/fxsjy/gonn: no buildable Go source files in /sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn`

Comment: @Shamoon did you type only `go get github.com/fxsjy/gonn`?

Comment: Yes, it apparently put it in `src`, but still has that error

Comment: @Shamoon can you access the chat? (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70428/discussion-between-shamoon-and-vonc)

Comment: @Shamoon tell me about it... anywhoozle, do you see now `/sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gon`? If yes, can you go in that folder, and type `go install` (before trying again in your own project)

Comment: Same: `$ go install
can't load package: package github.com/fxsjy/gonn: no buildable Go source files in /sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn`

Comment: @Shamoon do you see the same content as https://github.com/fxsjy/gonn in `/sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn` when you do a `cd /sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn`?

Comment: @Shamoon if yes, can you go one level below? `cd /sites/gopath/src/github.com/fxsjy/gonn/gonn`, and type `go install` from there?

Comment: that did it! needed to import `github.com/fxsjy/gonn/gonn`. How do I run this now?

Comment: @Shamoon go back to your project, and a `go install` should put your executable in `$GOPATH/bin`, which means you can type `autompg`  from anywhere to execute it.